# How to read system-wide notifications on Manjaro Linux?

Tags: python, notify

I am trying to write a Python script to get the info from a system notification, and performs actions after that.

How can I read the system wide notification text?

I am using [Notify](https://notify2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) to create and send notifications, but I'm unable to retrieve that data from another script.

This is my 'create' code

```
import gi
gi.require_version('Notify', '0.7')
from gi.repository import Notify
Notify.init("App Name")
Notify.Notification.new("Hi").show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The notifications go over DBus from the program to another program which displays them. You can capture the notifications by monitoring the DBus for all calls to the method `org.freedesktop.Notifications.Notify` via:

```
dbus-monitor interface=org.freedesktop.Notifications,member=Notify
```

This can also be done via the bindings with `eavesdrop='true'` added to that match string.